# Checking for a condition simultaneously in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to load data on a webpage when the scroll-bar reaches the end of the page. For this, I am using a custom Angular directive. Using a single Ajax call, the entire data are fetched, and at a time, 6 items are displayed on the page as:

```
<div ng-repeat="providersList in ( filteredproducts = ( providersList | filter:{ providerName: spsearch } | filter:{ citiesServicing: locationsearch }:ignoreNullComparator ))  | orderBy: 'rank' | limitTo: limit " >
    <a ng-href='{{providersList.detailPageLink}}' class="spntouch-link spnlistcard">...
```

I want to simultaneously check if more items remain in the fetched data,and display them if true. So, the thing is, when the scroll-bar hits the end of the page, it checks if more items remain, and if yes, it loads them on the page.

How do I check that simultaneously? Is this correct?

```
<div ng-repeat="providersList in ( filteredproducts = ( providersList | filter:{ providerName: spsearch } | filter:{ citiesServicing: locationsearch }:ignoreNullComparator ))  | orderBy: 'rank' | limitTo: limit " >
    <div when-scrolled="hasMoreItemsToShow(filteredproducts.length,limit) && showMoreItems()>
                   <a ng-href='{{providersList.detailPageLink}}' class="dnstouch-link dnslistcard">....
```

Will the above code do? I am very new to webD, and thus, please excuse if the question is too basic.

Thanks!

Comment: "Will the above code work"... Well, have you tried ? What was the result ?

Comment: My env is having some problems, and thus can't test it.